# Azure Media Services Merging Multiple videos with one audio stream

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I trying to build a bit of a complex solution using Azure Media Services. We have around 1000+ small video files, We will be pushing all these asserts to AMS using an automated job and generate around 10 video files which combine 5 out of 1000 videos with the same background track.

All Videos have the same frame rate/Res.

Based on the engagement of the first 5 videos(videos generated by a combination of 5 random asserts from 1000 small videos uploaded beforehand), we want to build 5 more videos(from the 1000 videos) based on data on the first 5 videos.

My question is, Is there a way on AMS to say I want to merge video asserts 10, 24. 345, 587 and 879 with a standard soundtrack and generate a new assert?

I been looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#concatenate but did get the answer that I needed.

I am not sure if I gave the full info required for the solution but happy to add more if required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support concatenation in our [v3 APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-v2-vs-v3) yet.

With v2 APIs, you can potentially achieve this scenario by:

1. Concatenating the videos first
2. Applying the background audio as an overlay on the concatenated video. You would need to make sure that the duration of the audio matches that of the concatenated video.